# Creating Menus in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Hey I want to create a menu which can collapse and have very good look in HTML and CSS. Like they are in all the sites I want to place then just under my header/

Comment: Hey, I want some alcohol.

Comment: use a search engine to look for that. this site is for specific programming problems (as in, you already have code, and one thing is not working as you want it)

Comment: ...and I want a pony! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: get from twitter.bootstrap's website.

Answer (score 0):

No surprise that you got so many downvotes. You query on google will give tonnes of results. The hint for you are tags **a.hover,display:none,display:block**